# How do I specify what version of Postgres to use in a Drone build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, version, drone.io

I use Drone for continuous integration and Postgresql as my database for a Ruby on Rails project. It appears that the default build on Drone uses an outdated version of pgsql. Ostensibly, the solution is clearly spelled out in [this thread](https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/786) on github, but I don't exactly know how to proceed with the instructions. I gather that I am supposed to "specify postgres:9.3," but where? And how?

Answer (score 1):

This goes in the `compose` section in your `.drone.yml` configuration file in the root of your repository. Here you can add separate docker containers to use in build. [Services / compose Drone docs](http://readme.drone.io/usage/overview/#services:68f80267fa3a50980dbb745a782b8dca)

```
build:
  image: node:$$NODE_VERSION
  commands:
  - npm test
compose:
  database:
    image: mongo:2.6
```